# Pandas: Add bool column if two fields match in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm new to pandas and struggling a little. I have two large dataframes with several 100000s lines. I extracted two columns of both and want to add a bool in the first dataset if two fields match exactly in both dataframes. As an example:

```
   0  1
0  a  b
1  a  c
2  a  d
3  a  e
4  b  a
5  b  b
6  b  c
7  b  d
######
   0  1
0  a  b
1  a  c
2  d  e
3  k  g
4  b  a
```

I would expect the result:

```
   0  1  2
0  a  b  True
1  a  c  True
2  a  d  False
3  a  e  False
4  b  a  True
5  b  b  False
6  b  c  False
7  b  d  False
```

I tried different things, but none of them worked:

```
t3 = (t1[[0]].isin(t2[[0]])) & (t1[[1]].isin(t2[[1]]))

    0   1
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
```

I guess the solution is very easy, but I cannot find how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and no parameter `on` for join by intersection of columns in both `DataFrame`s, then `rename` column and test if `both` values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='left').rename(columns={'_merge':2})
df[2] = df[2].eq('both')
print (df)
   0  1      2
0  a  b   True
1  a  c   True
2  a  d  False
3  a  e  False
4  b  a   True
5  b  b  False
6  b  c  False
7  b  d  False
```